# list All the hosted website from command line on IIS

Tags: windows, iis, command-line

How can we list All the hosted website from command-line on IIS?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You might have to run this as administrator.

```
appcmd list site
```

Directly from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771280(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I'm getting this  ERROR ( message:Configuration error 
Filename: redirection.config
Line Number: 0
Description: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
. )

Comment: @JavedAkhtar I have updated my answer, you might need to run cmd as administrator. Please see if this works.

Comment: You may need to run this command from the `%windir%\system32\inetsrv` (64 bit) or `%windir%\syswow64\inetsrv` (32 bit) directory.

Answer (score 20):

As @WolfyUK mentioned, you may need to run the command from the inetsrv directory.

**64 Bit:**

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list site
```

**32 Bit:**

```
%windir%\syswow64\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list site
```

The list site command will list all sites but you can also:

**List Individual Site by Name:**

```
...\appcmd.exe list site /name:"<site_name>"
```

**List Individual Site by Meta ID (Site ID No.):**

```
...\appcmd.exe list site /id:<site_number>
```

**List All Virtual Directories:**

```
...\appcmd.exe list vdir
```

Comment: another useful command related to this is `...\appcmd.exe list vdir` to list the virtual directories, helpful when looking for subdomain sites/folders.

Answer (score 3):

Please try power shell script

Get-WebApplication

Answer (score 3):

Please try the below command. It showed IIS site list successfully.

Get-Website