# How to export all sites and it's PHP version from IIS

Tags: php, windows, iis, export

I would like to export a list of all my sites and their current php version from IIS.

Anyone know if this is possible?

I've found this to export all my sites, but it's not enough info (no php version):

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list site /config /xml > c:\sites.xml
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744744/list-all-the-hosted-website-from-command-line-on-iis/13745030) might help

Comment: No sorry, that's exactly as i've tired already. but in my example above, i export it to xml as well.

Answer (score 0):

So after more research i found that IIS has a config-fil located in it's root:
windows -> system 32/64 -> inetsrv -> config

I took a copy of this file, edited the file to XML and imported it to Excel.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. It will be appreciated if you could mark yourself as an answer. So that your post could help more people.